# Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id _Nonnull' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, automatic-ref-counting

This code:

```
[selectedTagIndexes addObject: (int)sender.tag - 100];
```

produces an error:

> Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id _Nonnull' is disallowed with ARC

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide an outline of the *actual* problem you're facing along with what you've tried. Try to adhere to the guidelines laid out here when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 7):

You cannot directly convert here so use like this,

```
 [selectedTagIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sender.tag-100]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
[selectedTagIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:((int)sender.tag - 100)]];

//access like this
NSLog(@"%d",[[selectedTagIndexes objectAtIndex:0] intValue]);
```